# security measures reading mails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to read mails from Gmail and store them in my database.  The data are then displayed in my application.

Indeed I expect to have security issues. I am using Encode and Decode but I fear there might be sql injection or any other kind of attack as the user might send anything in the body of the mail and when reading and storing the data, there might be some kind of attacks.

I was not sure where to post this question, I am using asp.net MVC that`s why I have opted to post it around here.

Can anyone suggest what I can do to minimize attacks when downloading mails from Google.

Answer (score 0):

Always use [parametrized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) when sending SQL queries to your database. This way, no matter what garbage is thrown at it, it will be properly sanitized and you will be safe. Of course if you are already using an ORM this ORM probably already does that for you. Check the manual.